# How to play audio files randomly and separately in JS

Tags: javascript, dom-events, html5-audio

I created a small Kanye West Quote generator, and along with the button that fetches a random Kanye quote, I put in some audio files to play along (just three audio clips of Kanye saying something).

What I'm trying to do is: when the button is clicked to reveal a new quote, an audio (from the 3) should play. Currently, I have it that it will play, but all 3 audio files plays at once or two plays at once, and one plays separately on the next click.

Here is my code for the audio:

```
const kanyeBush = document.getElementById('bush');
const kanyeOpinion = document.getElementById('opinion');
const kanyeRobot = document.getElementById('robot');
let kanyeQuoteArray = [kanyeBush, kanyeOpinion, kanyeRobot];

const kanyeSounds = () => {
        let kanyeSoundbite = kanyeQuoteArray.forEach( sound => {
            sound.play();
        });
        let audio = new Audio(kanyeSoundbite);
        audio.play();
}
```

I then ran this inside my fetch code:

```
const kanyeQuote = async () => {
    const kanyeResponse = await fetch(kanyeApi);
    const quoteJson = await kanyeResponse.json();
    const randomQuote = document.createElement('h3');
    quoteBox.innerHTML = "";
    randomQuote.innerHTML = quoteJson.quote;
    quoteBox.appendChild(randomQuote);
    kanyeBtn.classList.toggle('hidden');
    newQuoteBtn.classList.toggle('hidden');
    kanyeSounds();
}


newQuoteBtn.addEventListener('click',kanyeQuote);
kanyeBtn.addEventListener('click', kanyeQuote)
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set sound.play in forEach for all of them... so they play together. you have to specified with one you expect to play. For e.g you can use random index

```js
  const kanyeSounds = () => {
            let bitIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * kanyeQuoteArray.length))
            let kanyeSoundbite = kanyeQuoteArray.forEach( (sound, index) => {
                sound.pause(); // reset previous 
                sound.currentTime = 0; // reset position
                if(index === bitIndex) sound.play();
            });
            
            let audio = new Audio(kanyeSoundbite);
            audio.play();
    }
```

Comment: I wish I could provide you with something valuable, but unfortunately all I have is a genuine thank you. It worked. 
I don't know why I couldn't think about putting in another parameter in the forEach (as I'm very new to this world). Thank you again!